# android - ViewPager doesn't show its content

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a recyclerView with images and it's supposed that an image opens in ViewPager by click. I added ViewPager in the root of my layout.

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

This is pager_item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@color/black"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ivPhotoInPager"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is my custom adapter.

```
class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
    User.Photo[] photos;

    public CustomPagerAdapter(Context context,User.Photo[] photos) {
        mContext = context;
        mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.photos=photos;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return photos.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_item, container, false);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivPhotoInPager);
        loadRoundedImageToSrc(ApiHelper.API_HTTP + "/" + photos[position].photo.image, imageView, 15f, null);
        container.addView(itemView);

        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((RelativeLayout) object);
    }
}
```

In the activity I do:

```
pager.setAdapter(new CustomPagerAdapter(getApplicationContext(),user.photo));
```

And in OnClick:

```
pager.setCurrentItem(position);
```

But nothing is shown. What can be the problem?

Comment: Have you tried returning imageView instead of itemView in the instantiateItem() method?

Comment: just tried it. didn't help

Comment: `container.addView(VIew)` defaults to `WRAP_CONTENT`. Maybe you should try `container.addView(view, ViewGroup.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.MATCH_PARENT)` and also change you ImageView on the XML to match parent

Comment: As well as making `instantiateItem()` return `imageView`, see if changing `isViewFromObject()  from view == ((RelativeLayout) object)` to `view == ((ImageView) object)` and changing `destroyItem()` from `container.removeView((RelativeLayout) object)` to `container.removeView((ImageView) object)`, and changing imageView to be instatied like `ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context)` makes the ViewPager show its content

Comment: Thank you guys! The funniest thing is that ViewPager was among other widgets and I had to change its _elevation_ so that it become above the other elements. And now idk what to do with pre-Lollipop versions

Comment: So was the  ViewPager not showing its content because of its elevation? On pre-Lollipop versions try and and see if having the ViewPager's XML code written after the views you want it to appear over